# Mod Rewriting directory structure to appear differently

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hate having to ask for help, but editing .htaccess is one of those things in life that I cannot and will not ever wrap my head around. I've been at this for months trying to learn, and I've got nowhere. I finally admit defeat and come seeking help!

I have a directory:-

http://example.com/images/blog/year/month/anyfilename.jpg

Which I would like, if it's possible. To always appear as:-

http://example.com/pix/anyfilename.jpg

I would then continue to upload files in the correct year/month directories, which would only be visible to me. Externally to visitors, they would see the latter url if they viewed the image (I can take care of parsing the links in the PHP pages to match the rewritten "virtual" directory, myself so that wont be a problem).

The times I've come close to having it working, the images were no longer visible, which makes sense, but I thought the point of being able to rewrite URL's was to avoid having to move files too?

I have RewriteEngine on, and Options +FollowSymlinks and I know it's all setup correctly as other rules and redirects work. It's just this that doesn't want to play.

I have no examples to show as I have no examples that work. I've searched everywhere, come close to an answer but never anything close enough to what I'm needing, to actually work for me. I'm out of ideas.

Help me Obi-Wan Overflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do with just mod-rewrite. The problem is you have multiple locations where the file could live and your rewrite rule doesn't accept any kind of input of where to find it. You could do something like http://www.example.com/pix-month-year/anyfilename.jpg. Mod-rewrite isn't a scripting language.

Alternatively, you could create a PHP script which you pass in a file name, and it could search through the image directories until it finds a match, and pass through the image data to the browser. (Remember to account for the same filename in multiple folders.)

Your mod_rewrite would simply be something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^pix/(.*)$ find-pix.php?filename=$1
```